# How to define multiple types for one event?

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

Came upon a quite similar scenario as described [HERE](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18163/best-practice-multiple-event-types-or-custom-data-fields): event 1 (initial workshop) is the kickoff-"lesson" for **two types** of event-series, which will continue in two different date sequences afterwards.

The scenario: event 1 is an initial workshop-lesson of an event-series continuing during the whole year AND it is the first date of an intensive short training course of one month.

With the [advanced events extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/advancedevents/en/latest/) for the additional event registrations and using price sets, I could easily achieve the desired registration behaviour for both of the event-series.

But: **How can I define two or multiple additional event types for the first kickoff-event?**
Using custom fields is not an option, as the event types are predefined in CiviEvent.

Any hint would be highly appreciated. Most probably, I don't realize at the moment, that there would be an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

We built this extension which operates on the basis that you can set one Event as the parent of other events, and then when a person registers for the parent Event they get registered for all the child events too.

I don't think we have touched it for a couple of years but assume the battery won't be flat.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/multiple-event-registration

Comment: Thank you for your reply, participant registration for both event series is not a problem. The main concern is that, if the first event of the series can only be declared i. e. as "workshop", it will be visible in the frontend event overviews under "workshops" only. But it is as well an "intense training" start-event. Under the respective section in the frontend views, it won't be displaying, because it is only ONE event type eligible/visible. Does your extension allow to chose more than one event type?

Comment: Sorry - i really didn't read your problem closely enough, and will remove my answer as it is not at all helpful